# Adding parent window's CSS to child window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a pop-up window with a printable version of a small portion of the  main window. I'm using Meteor, so the HTML and CSS files are all programmatically generated.

What I'd like to do is use Javascript to read all the linked CSS files in the parent window and append them to the child window.

```js
var childWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=350,height=150");
var childDoc    = childWindow.document;
var childHead   = childDoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

$('link').each(function(index,element){
  childLink = childDoc.createElement("link");
  childLink.rel  = "stylesheet";
  childLink.href = element.href;
  childHead.appendChild(childLink);
});
childDoc.write(myHtml);
```

But its not working. It appears that `childHead` is referring to the head of the parent document, not the child. I'm not sure if this is a security thing I'm running afoul of or just have a mistake in the code.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was appending something to the body with `childDoc.write(myHtml);`

Previous to this, the CSS would not load, but once I actually passed in a few divs, the CSS showed up without any other modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a very similar thing on one of my pages.  I just use the 'parent' page to write everything and it works fine.  Here is how it works for me.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dzCz/1/) in action.
You'll notice that it only prints the stuff from the `printMe` div.  Also, the printed page has all the same exact scripts and styles that the parent page does.

```
some stuff NOT to print
<div id="printMe" class="ui-selectable-helper">
    I should be printed, but not the other stuff.
</div>
more stuff NOT to print

$(function(){
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'printWin', 'height=600, width=900, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');

    //create a new HEAD with the exact same content as the main page
    var writeMe = ('<body><head>' + $('head').html() + '</head><html>');

    //grab the content of the printMe div and use it on the print page
    writeMe += ("<div>" + $('#printMe')[0].outerHTML + "</div>");
    writeMe += ('</html></body>');    
    printWindow.document.write(writeMe);
    printWindow.document.close();    
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();  

    //you might even use this next line if you want the 'popup' window to go away as soon as they have finished printing.
    //printWindow.close();
});
```

Note: I am just using the `class="ui-selectable-helper"` to show you that indeed the CSS pages are transferring properly to the new popup window.

Comment: Actually, it just shows up in the body. At least that's the way it is in chrome.