# Is anyway to use parent window's css without reloading it?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is there anyway to use parent window's css without reloading it in the iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903708/adding-parent-windows-css-to-child-window-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, iframe is a new window in all aspects with no relation to the host DOM, except for being able to communicate via .contentWindow and .parent if they're both on the same domain.